# How to replace multiple spaces and newlines with one blank line

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

How to remove multiple spaces and newlines in a string, but preserve at least one blank line for each group of blank lines.

For example, change:

```
"This      is



a        string.




Something."
```

to

```
"This is

a string.

Something."
```

I'm using `.trim()` to strip whitespace from the beginning and end of a string, but I couldn't find anything for removing multiple spaces and newlines in a string.

I would like to keep just one whitespace and one newline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The one-line solution to remove multiple spaces/newlines, but preserve at least one blank line from multiple blank lines:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?m)(^ *| +(?= |$))", "").replaceAll("(?m)^$([\r\n]+?)(^$[\r\n]+?^)+", "$1");
```

Each individual line is trimmed too.

---

Here's some test code:

```
String str = "   This       is\r\n    " + 
        "\r\n" + 
        "   \r\n   " + 
        " \r    \n   \n  " +
        "\r\n" + 
        "                a        string.   ";
str = str.trim().replaceAll("(?m)(^ *| +(?= |$))", "").replaceAll("(?m)^$([\r\n]+?)(^$[\r\n]+?^)+", "$1");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
This is

a string.
```

Comment: My head started smoking at this regex, +1 though for the one-liner

Comment: I'll make a deal: if you accept this answer, I'll explain the regex :)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not OP owner, so I can't accept it. I could explain it to myself by looking up those special constucts in [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)'s javadoc, but it would be greate if you put yours in the answer for the rest of the users ;-) ... btw, just tested it, it seems to leave one space at the beginning of the last line -> `' a string.'`

Comment: @A4L I fixed the regex regarding the leading space: I changed the order of the alternation in the first regex to *first* match spaces at start of lines, then if they are not found to match other multiple spaces (regex will find alternate matches in the order they are coded). To explain the regex would take a while. I don't have time now - maybe later (I'll let you know)

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept this answer. A4L wrote a good solution, but I think that your one-line solution is better.

Comment: for Kotlin string.trim().replace("(?m)(^ *| +(?= |$))".toRegex(), "").replace("(?m)^$([\r\n]+?)(^$[\r\n]+?^)+".toRegex(), "$1")

Comment: @SaiKiran `replace()` does a plain text (not regex) replacement. Your code is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

The previous advice will trim all whitespace, including the linefeeds and replace them with a single space.

```
 text.replaceAll("\\n\\s*\\n", "\\n").replaceAll("[ \\t\\x0B\\f]+", " ").trim());
```

First it replaces any instances of linefeeds with only whitespace between them with a single linefeed, then it trims down any other whitespace to a single space ignoring linefeeds.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with after a bit of testing...

```
public String keepOneWS(String str) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\s+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

    Pattern pBlank = Pattern.compile("[ \t]+");
    String newLineReplacement = System.getProperty("line.separator") + 
            System.getProperty("line.separator");

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        if(pBlank.matcher(m.group(1)).matches()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, " ");   
        } else {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, newLineReplacement);
        }
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    return sb.toString().trim();
}

public void testKeepOneWS()  {
    String str = "   This   \t    is\r\n    " + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "   \r\n   " + 
            " \r    \n  \t  \n  " +
            "\r\n" + 
            "                a   \t     string.   \t ";
    String expected = "This is" + System.getProperty("line.separator")+ 
            System.getProperty("line.separator") + "a string.";
    String actual = keepOneWS(str);
    System.out.println("'" + actual + "'");
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

After a goup of whitespace is captured, it is checked whether it consists only of spaces, if yes then that goup is replaced by one single space, otherwise the goup consits of spaces and line terminators, in this case the group is replaced by one line terminator.

The output is:

```
'This is

a string.'
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, just if there are more than two newlines, I would like to keep one empty row, and remove other empty rows, like in my example. I know my explanation in question is not good, since I wrote that I would like to keep just one whitespace and one newline. I forgot that one newline is for new row, and two newlines are for one empty row. I hope that you understand what am I trying to say.

Comment: @user3051755, I have edited the answer, will this work for you? You could try to play with the multiplicity in the regex, in the example above I use `+` for at least one or more, you could use `{2,}` for at least 2 or more.